# Best way to run script via a /bin/bash shell script in multiple environments?

Tags: python, bash, bin

I have a python script which I run on localhost and development in command line with argument, sth as `python script.py development` - on development and `python script.py localhost` - on localhost.

Now I want to run this script - when I running script `/bin/bash sh`,
so I want to run this script from `/bin/.bash` script.
I added in headers in sh script: `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

In what way I can achieve this?

```bash
do
    if [ $1 == "local" ]; then
      python script.py $1

    elif [ $1 == "development" ]; then
      python script.py $1
```

*What* I can do to improve this script?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What do you mean by `/bin/bash sh`? Why would you use `#!/usr/bin/env python` in a "sh script"? Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Since `$1` already contains what you want, the conditional is unnecessary.

If your script is a Bash script, you should put `#!/bin/bash` (or your local equivalent) in the shebang line.  However, this particular script uses no Bash features, and so might usefully be coded to run POSIX `sh` instead.

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  local|development) ;;
  *) echo "Syntax: $0 local|development" >&2; exit 2;;
esac

exec python script.py "$1"
```

A more useful approach is to configure your local system to run the script directly with `./script.py` or similar, and let the script itself take care of parsing its command-line arguments.  How exactly to do that depends on your precise environment, but on most U*x-like systems, you would put `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of `script.py` itself, and `chmod +x` the file.

Comment: Perhaps see also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you wanted...

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! "$@" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $1 (local|development) "
  exit
fi

if [ "$1" == "local" ]; then
    python script.py "$1"
    echo "$1"
elif
    [ "$1" == "development" ]; then
    python script.py "$1"
    echo "$1"
fi
```

Save the bash code above into a file named let's say `script.sh`. The make it executable: `chmod +x script.sh`. Then run it:

```
./script.sh
```

If no argument is specified, the script will just print an info about how to use it.

`./script.sh local` - executes python script.py local

`./script.sh development` - executes python script.py development

You can comment the lines with echo, they were left there just for debugging purposes (add a **#** in front of the echo lines to comment them).